# Stepper motor holding current

Tags: stepper-motor

I am using this [5V Stepper Motor](https://ttmotor.en.alibaba.com/product/60648149640-220017831/12mm_5V_DC_stepper_mini_motor_of_gm12_15by_100.html) and [Driver IC](https://www.pololu.com/product/2134). My motor is working fine but it consumes 10-20mA when there is no pulse. The circuit should consume power only when there is a pulse. I have attached the driver circuit and schematic of the communicator. My question is how to drop the holding current of the motor by that the motor doesn't consume power. Or if you got any idea or any modifications I can do. Please help me with your ideas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Turn off when it is not needed.

Comment: (Whoops... Unintentionally deleted my original comment! That comment was->) I'm not sure what you are asking. If you shut off the current in the stepper motor's windings, there will be nothing to hold the motor's rotor (shaft) stationary against the load torque, and the load can then turn the rotor to any position it wants relative to the stator; is that the effect you are trying to achive? Or are you trying to figure out a way to "turn off" the stepper motor when it is not needed.

Comment: The Pololu DRV8834 "Low-Voltage Stepper Motor Driver Carrier" board you are using has two inputs labeled /SLEEP (a.k.a., nSLEEP) and /ENBL (a.k.a., nENBL). Those control signals look promising (in other words, read the documentation on Pololu's website, and read the data sheet for the Texas Instruments DRV8834 IC).

Comment: YOu need to show the stepper driver circuit not the communicator.

Comment: @JimFischer issue with sleep is it resets the internals. And ENABLE is just plain weird...

Comment: @Dhinesh: (1) This is your fourth question on this project in a month. I'm quite sure that if you described what you are trying to make that you would get some very useful suggestions about how to avoid the complexity you are experiencing. It seems that you have spent a month trying to avoid buying a three-pole slip-ring. (2) If you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar you can embed an editable schematic without a subscription. That way anyone can copy your schematic, make edits and post it in their answer without having to redraw the whole thing.

Comment: @Transistor 1. Yes, I agree with you. Due to unawareness in the circuit design, I am having this kind of problem. Maybe in the future, I will have to think about what are the factors affect me while designing. But this stage I am sure that the circuit behaves as my expectation except for this tiny current draw. I heard from the Pololu that there is no option available in DRV8834 to reduce the holding current. 2. Yes, that makes I can add the driver schematic which helps others to redraw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you  have spare HC14s you can do it this way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6EClu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Tie the _STEP input to the same place the current HC14 gets it's input from so you take another copy of the Step Signal and do not affect the current one.

The circuit is a simple one-shot that will hold the _ENABLE line low for a period after any STEP pulse arrives. Note, the first step pulse may be ignored by the driver. I have no idea how far apart your step pulses are so I chose values in this circuit to hold the enable low for the half a second ball-park.

However, since I believe you are not just using full steps to move the motor you will lose position each time you stop stepping and the ENABLE goes away.

A better alternative would be to drop the current in the driver. The circuit above can be modified to do that like so.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNWhPv.png)</sup>

Note the carrier has a spot for an SMT resistor which you could use for R2, or you need to jumper that spot on the carrier. You need to chose a value for R2 to reduce VREF to the minimal level that will still allow the motor to hold position.

**Further Explanation...**
In case you have not figured this out yet.. This is what you should end up with (Note I changed R2 to a variable resistor so you can adjust the holding current.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0aKBx.png)</sup>

On board the carrier they gave you a potentiometer that lets you divide the reference voltage that the driver creates, VREFO, and feeds that smaller voltage back into the current setting reference voltages AVREF and BVREF. That voltage then sets your run time current.

The designer also brought out the wiper on that pot to a pin on the carrier. As such, by attaching another resistor to ground, though a switch, you can change the divider to produce a smaller voltage when desired.

The circuit I have suggested will do exactly that when there have been no step pulses for a while.

**BTW:** In case you had not realized, in your current circuit, holding the STEP line high at the source will turn off the driver entirely.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69178/discussion-on-answer-by-trevor-stepper-motor-holding-current).

Comment: Hi, Trevor, I am getting this signal on C1 while pulsing https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXMvX.png  is that the time constant has to be fast? This is the image I am getting on M1 gate while not pulsing https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZdkA.png

Comment: I have increased the time constant to 0.3sec but still, I am getting the same signal. Where am I making mistake?

Comment: @Dhinesh rise time should be fast, fall time should be a LOT longer than that... like a quarter or half a second, so I don't know why is so short. The gate voltage is more troublesome...

Comment: @Dhinesh  show me your 5V rail voltage.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfWa6.jpg This is the breadboard connection to make sure connections are correct. 2. This is the image showing 5v goes into second input inverter and comes out from the second inverter (without connecting D1)https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeyAF.png. Is that what you want? Once I have connected to D1 the pulse gets to 3V and the fall time is short

Comment: Those yellow and blue wires going to the 2nd invertor look like they come from the same slot in the bread-board and are shorted beside the mosfet

Comment: YOu need to move the cap and yellow wire over beside the 1Meg resistor, and ditch the brown jumper

Comment: ahh I got it. I will do the change

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhP1Q.jpg This is the new breadboard connection. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynOCI.png This output is taken from second inverter output to C1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qttV7.png This is the output taken from second inverter output to Gate M1

Comment: @Dhinesh now you have the diode shorted. Remember. rows on the breadboard are one connection

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsqWF.jpg breadboard connection and https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVdaf.png I don't see any pulse on the D1

Comment: @Dhinesh dude.. did you not get any sleep last night? Seriously, look and check what you are doing? Why are there two yellow wires coming from the cap?

Comment: one of the yellow wire I have used for oscilloscope and another yellow wire goes to the second inverter input

Comment: @Dhinesh then figure it out.. It is not that complicated.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1tpT.png I am getting the pulse across the resistor but as soon as I connect the cap https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWg6S.png the voltage across the cap goes high and the pulse disappears.

Comment: @Dhinesh that is right... at that time-base you should not see much... wind your scope out to like 0.25s / div

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h53o.png top pulse measured at the gate M1 and bottom one measured at the cap.

Comment: Mosfet threshold value is 2-4V will that be a problem?

Comment: @Dhinesh looks good  to me

Comment: so when there is no pulse this MOSFET will turn on and control the driver current. There is still current consumption. Where is the mistake?

Comment: @Dhinesh that is correct, but the holding current should be a lot less.

Comment: I am really still confused it is consuming 10mA-20mA. Is anything wrong with the motor or Driver? Did I damage them?

Comment: How long does the cap stay charged after a single pulse? What value did you use for R2, and what position is the POT at on the carrier?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJJNf.jpg the answer is 2sec, R2 is  10k and .50mv is the pot set to

Comment: @Dhinesh 10K will be a bit large then if you are that close to the Pot bottom. You really would be better using like a 10 turn pot for R2.

Comment: Which means I can vary the R2 and find out when it gets down to zero amperes?  2. can I try swapping the minimum  R2 value to find out as well?

Comment: @Dhinesh you do not want it to be zero amps. The whole point of this approach is to minimize the current you use to hold position. Yes using a pot will let you adjust it down till it no longer holds reliably. You can try any smaller value you want for now.

Comment: @Dhinesh if you want ZERO amps, just keep the step line high at the micro.

Comment: Hi, Trevor, I've managed to find this 100k trimmer (3296W-1-104 ) but varying the value of R2 from (0 ohms to 10K) is not helping me much to reduce the current. Is that the connection correct  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeMYo.jpg

Comment: @Dhinesh hard to tell at that angle. You need to get your meter out and see that it does to the VREF value at the driver chip...

Comment: you are right turning the trimmer doesn't make any impact on the Vref pin on the carrier board.

Comment: I found that if I set the Vref=57.5mV using an onboard potentiometer and by adjusting the value R2=2.1K I am getting the Vref to 48.2mV (it is dropping very much though) and the current consumption is getting from 30mA to 20mA. is that sounds right to you? is that what maximum I can control the holding current of the motor?

Comment: @Dhinesh if it is wired right you should be able to get vref all the way down to zero at one end of the pot. Make sure you set the vref on the board with this pull down circuit disconnected though.

Comment: it doesn't sound right to me. Somewhere I am making mistake. Vref is not dropping down to zero. I will send you the clear connections image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUKc0.jpg is the connections look right?

Comment: Hi, Trevor, the pot is behaving well. I want to double check with you here I've set the Vref-20.2mV using the R2-247ohm and the current I am getting is zero amp(when there is no pulse) and the motor is running fine (when there is a pulse it goes to 20mA which is normal). But as soon as the motor is stopped the current again goes to 10mA. is this approach correct? you've already mentioned me that it will not go to zero. so this is the holding current limit? Please correct me

Comment: @Dhinesh That is correct this circuit lowers the holding current only. If you want it shut down entirely, use the step line.

Comment: is that step in are you talking about? what are the modifications needed?

Comment: @Dhinesh ... please use your head. What happens to the 12V supply to the stepper side when the STEP in line is high  ?

Comment: when step in line is high then it will disable the 12V supply. But the code has to be changed right on the microcontroller to make a step in high?

Comment: @Dhinesh yes code would need to change.

Comment: great, that makes sense to me.

Comment: Hi Trevor hope you are good. Just a question to you. I've found that when there is a pulse 12V modulated signal get down to 0V. If that is the case it will affect the voltage regulator right? because of 0V, the motor won't get power from the regulator right. Could you please clarify this for me

Comment: @Dhinesh the circuit is designed so that the pulses are short enough the capacitor before the regulator, C1, keeps the rail up long enough for the regulator to keep working. If you hold it in that state too long, yes the regulator etc will shut down. That is a bonus function. The bigger C1 is the more tolerant it will be.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I tried using a voltage divider next to transmitter circuit to make the 12v modulated pulse to 5v by that when there is pulse it is converted to 5v pulse and when there is no pulse it will stay at 5v but the voltage regulator is not working. Any suggestions could help me a lot.

Comment: @Dhinesh I have no idea what and why you are messing with it.

Comment: If there is pulse for a long then the motor will lose its 5v right ? That’s why I am concerned now.

Comment: @Dhinesh If you hold the step line high yes you will cut the power. But a typical 2uS step pulse will not be noticed.. assuming you are not stepping at like hundreds of kHz. if you have occasional wider pulses.. increase the capacitor size.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I have to try this. Thanks for your help!!!